# Are "às vezes" and "de vez em quando" completely interchangeable?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, diferenças, sinônimos

Can I replace “às vezes” with “de vez em quando” in all situations or are there contexts in which this is not possible or would be awkward?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While they are to a large extent interchangeable, *às vezes* has a better synonym in *por vezes* and *de vez em quando* in *de vez em vez* among others.

*De vez em quando* means something close to *once in a while*. There is some occurrence that is repeated infrequently and spaced out. So you say:

> Críticas e controvérsias em relação às suas decisões surgem *de vez em quando*.

*De vez em quando* stresses that these controversies resurface periodically, but with a long period. Here, *às vezes* would not be as good. Also, *às vezes* would work better before the verb (and move the subject after the verb: *Às vezes surgem críticas...*).

On the other hand, *às vezes* doesn't necessary carry the same idea that the occurrences are spaced out, and simply implies that something is infrequent, as in this example, where the implication is that it's not even *that* infrequent:

> Das seis da manhã às duas da tarde, *às vezes*, nem dez contos se fazem.

It's perfectly reasonable to assume that there would be spells where the business is bad, without their being spaced out.

Another example where *de vez em quando* doesn't work that well:

> Vou com ele aos treinos, almoço com ele, *às vezes* vou ao ginásio.

Comment: Fully agree with this answer. "de vez em quando" has a much stronger time character than "às vezes", probably like "every now and then" compared to "sometimes".

Answer (score 4):

Segundo o sitio [Sinônimos](https://www.sinonimos.com.br/as-vezes/) ambas as expressões são sinônimos.

> Sinônimo de às vezes
>       7 sinônimos de às vezes para 1 sentido da expressão às vezes:
>
> Em certas ocasiões: 1 raramente, poucas vezes, de quando em quando, de
>   vez em quando, ocasionalmente, por vez, por vezes.

Porém se olharmos a definição no dicionário [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/vez), há uma pequena diferença:

> **às vezes** • Em alguns casos ou ocasiões. = POR VEZES
>
> **de vez em quando** • Com intervalos; de tempos a tempos. = DE QUANDO EM
>   VEZ, OCASIONALMENTE

Com falante nativo, eu acredito que em 99% das vezes seriam sinônimos. Eu não consigo inclusive achar uma situação onde não poderiam ser.

Além disso, eu usaria **às vezes** em situações mais formais e **de vez em quando** em situações mais informais.

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically speaking, "às vezes" and "de vez em quando" are always interchangeable. When you get right down to it, however, there are situations where "às vezes" sounds more idiomatic than "de vez em quando". For instance, we can use either one in the examples below but, **to my ears**, **imho**, "às vezes" sounds **more idiomatic**. Perhaps because it is at the beginning of a sentence.

- "---------- eu penso, será que ela realmente gosta de mim?"
- "---------- eu acho que você me esconde alguma coisa.
- "---------- as duas palavras podem significar exatamente a mesma coisa, mas nem sempre.
- "---------- eu posso até ser mal-educado, mas isso é raro.
- "---------- esse tipo de sangramento é apenas decorrente de fragilidade capilar.

In other situations, it isn't about being idiomatic. It's a matter of semantics.  **Only "às vezes" can be used when it is a synonym for "talvez"**.

- Vamos com calma, ---------- ela só estava querendo agradar.
- Não se irrite, ----------- ele só estava brincando.
- ------------ foi alguma coisa que você comeu e não lembra.